# ASUS Laptop doesn't turn on, CPU gets hot. Have I fried my motherboard?

Tags: laptop, cpu, motherboard, asus-laptop

I was (foolishly) trying to repair a broken trackpad flat cable by connecting/disconnecting it while the laptop was turned on. All of a sudden, the screen started going crazy. I turned the laptop off and it won't turn on again.

I also noticed that the CPU gets insanely hot if I attempt to turn the laptop on. Have I fried the motherboard? Is there anything to do about it other than replacing it?

Laptop: ASUS ROG GL752VW.

Comment: Why exactly were you doing this with the machine on? A processor is supposed to get hot.  Your not supposed to be touching the CPU while the machine is turned on.  If the cooling is functioning then it should be fine

Comment: Because I was too lazy to turn it off, try inserting the cable and turn it on again. It is incredibly hot, as in it burnt my finger, not the normal motherboard hot.

Comment: How are you touching the CPU if it has a cooler on it?  If it doesn’t it then, install it, and stop touching your cpu